# Change description element text on image click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 7 images of 7 different characters next to each other, (in a row), and I want to add text below them, I want the text to change depending on the image I click.
Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Cine</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/80" alt="">
  <img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/81" alt="">
  <img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/82" alt="">
  <img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/83" alt="">
  <img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/84" alt="">
  <img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/85" alt="">
  <img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/86" alt="">
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the desired text inside the IMG's `alt` attribute (which is needed anyways for A11Y).
On click, populate the description element from that `alt` attribute value:

```js
const elsImages = document.querySelectorAll(".personajes_edge");
const elImgDesc = document.querySelector("#img-desc");

const showDesc = (elImg) => {
  elsImages.forEach(elI => elI.classList.toggle("is-active", elI === elImg));
  elImgDesc.textContent = elImg.getAttribute("alt");
};

elsImages.forEach((elImg) => {
  elImg.addEventListener("click", () => showDesc(elImg));
});
```

```css
.personajes_edge {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
} 
.personajes_edge.is-active {
  scale: 1.1;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 1rem #0008;
}
```

```html
<img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/80" alt="Some image description">
<img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/81" alt="Lorem ipsum">
<img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/82" alt="Dolor sit amet">
<img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/83" alt="4 Stack Overflow">
<img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/84" alt="Consectetur adipiscing">
<img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/85" alt="Elit consequenti">
<img class="personajes_edge" src="//picsum.photos/86" alt="Forme adeo sempras">

<p id="img-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
```

Comment: @cursos3 it’s worth studying this answer for its sensible and semantically accurate use of JS and HTML and the emphasis on accessibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Cine</title>
    <script>
        function changeText(imageNumber) {
            var text = document.getElementById("text");
            switch (imageNumber) {
                case 1:
                    text.innerHTML = "Text for Image 1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    text.innerHTML = "Text for Image 2";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    text.innerHTML = "Text for Image 3";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    text.innerHTML = "Text for Image 4";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    text.innerHTML = "Text for Image 5";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    text.innerHTML = "Text for Image 6";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    text.innerHTML = "Text for Image 7";
                    break;
                default:
                    text.innerHTML = "Default Text";
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="personajes_edge" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="" onclick="changeText(1)">
    <img class="personajes_edge" src="https://picsum.photos/51" alt="" onclick="changeText(2)">
    <img class="personajes_edge" src="https://picsum.photos/52" alt="" onclick="changeText(3)">
    <img class="personajes_edge" src="https://picsum.photos/53" alt="" onclick="changeText(4)">
    <img class="personajes_edge" src="https://picsum.photos/54" alt="" onclick="changeText(5)">
    <img class="personajes_edge" src="https://picsum.photos/55" alt="" onclick="changeText(6)">
    <img class="personajes_edge" src="https://picsum.photos/56" alt="" onclick="changeText(7)">

    <p id="text">Default Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onclick` should be discouraged in favor of the preferred `addEventListener`. Also, undeferred `<script>` is better placed in a non-render-blocking manner - right before the closing `</body>` tag; not in `<head>`. Also, using an object or an array seems cleaner than using a lengthy `switch case break`

Comment: It worked well thx